# Manipulate the data from two not linked servers

Tags: sql-server, server, data-quality

At the moment I have **two Microsoft SQL Servers** with **schema_1** and ****schema_2**** respectively. Previously, these two schemes were on one server, and I wrote queries in which I could access these two schemes at once. Now, for some reason, these two schemes have been carried over to different servers and there is no way to make a linked server (and replication of the schema too). I have a question, how can I take data from two unconnected servers in order to write queries.

I have an assumption that I can use Python in order to read a table from one server, and then from another, but the question arises, how to implement complex logic in a query that used to be in SQL, and will now be rewritten in python, such approach may be ineffective.

My queries are more focused on the quality check with complex logic, could you advise a tool in which this can be implemented (except PowerBI) or data forums where I can ask this question.

Comment: Why is there no way to create a linked server between the two?

Comment: @squillman such situation has arisen, load for one server

Comment: If having a linked server or replication between the two is not possible, then you could set up another server that would have linked servers to the other 2 servers and pull the data in there to do your combined processing.  Outside of that you either need to convert your SQL logic into something else (you mention Python).  However, recommendations for tools and libraries are explicitly off topic on Stackoverflow.